# Constraining a MessageDialog to be more petite

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, bing-maps, windows-store-apps

In checking out the sample Windows Store Bing app "bingPushpin," I see that this code:

```
private async void pushpinTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Hello from Seattle.");
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

...causes a "MessageDialog" that spreads across the entire frame.

Surely this is not the Windows Store (nee "Metro") way of doing it. How can you specify the MessageDialog takes up no more space than necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width will always occupy the client area and the height will be dependent on the amount of text that needs to be displayed.

see [Designing a Message Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh738364.aspx)

Comment: That seems like an odd way of doing it; "use just enough space" seems better than "take all the space"

Comment: the way I look at it is that one of the core philosophies behind the Windows 8 design is consistency of experience for the end user.  It's 'different' no arguing that, but I also think of how many times I've missed seeing modal dialogs in traditional windows because they don't have as commanding or consistent a presence.  As the other answer indicated, flyouts could be an option giving you a bit more individuality as well.

Comment: In this particular case, I'd say it's definitely a case of overkill; I'm just surprised that MS has a semi-official sample app that looks so ... inelegant (YMMV). The map looks great, but the outsized MessageDialog? No, that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look to the Flyout control that is available in the Callisto Control Toolkit: https://github.com/timheuer/callisto.

Comment: Thanks for the link; I wonder if it's going to be expanded, or at least updated - in electronic years, May was aeons ago.